# How to replace multiple matches / groups with regexes?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

Normally we would write the following to replace one match:

```
namesRegex = re.compile(r'(is)|(life)', re.I)
replaced = namesRegex.sub(r"butter", "There is no life in the void.")
print(replaced)

output:
There butter no butter in the void.
```

What i want is to replace, probably using back references, each group with a specific text. Namely i want to replace the first group (is) with "are" and the second group (life) with "butterflies".

Maybe something like that. But the following is not working code.

```
namesRegex = re.compile(r'(is)|(life)', re.I)
replaced = namesRegex.sub(r"(are) (butterflies)", r"\1 \2", "There is no life in the void.")
print(replaced)
```

Is there a way to replace multiple groups in one statement in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a replacement by lambda, mapping the keywords you want to associate:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(is)|(life)', lambda x: {'is': 'are', 'life': 'butterflies'}[x.group(0)], "There is no life in the void.")
'There are no butterflies in the void.'
```

Comment: what if every patter needs to be output of function

Answer (score 4):

You can define a map of keys and replacements first and then use a [lambda function in replacement](https://thebitguru.com/blog/782-lambda-functions-in-python):

```
>>> repl = {'is': 'are', 'life': 'butterflies'}
>>> print re.sub(r'is|life', lambda m: repl[m.group()], "There is no life in the void.")
There are no butterflies in the void.
```

I will also suggest you to use word boundaries around your keys to safeguard your search patterns:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\b(?:is|life)\b', lambda m: repl[m.group()], "There is no life in the void.")
There are no butterflies in the void.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a dictionary with search-replacement values and use a simple `\w+` regex to match words:

```
import re
dt = {'is' : 'are', 'life' : 'butterflies'}
namesRegex = re.compile(r'\w+')
replaced = namesRegex.sub(lambda m: dt[m.group()] if m.group() in dt else m.group(), "There is no life in the void.")
print(replaced)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hXoy98)

With this approach, you do not have to worry about creating a too large regex pattern based on alternation. You may adjust the pattern to include word boundaries, or only match letters (e.g. `[\W\d_]+`), etc. as per the requirements. The main point is that the pattern should match all the search terms that are keys in the dictionary.

The `if m.group() in dt else m.group()` part is checking if the found match is present as a key in the dictionary, and if it is not, just returns the match back. Else, the value from the dictionary is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to replace specific words, go no further than [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```py
s = "There is no life in the void."
s.replace('is', 'are').replace('life', 'butterflies')  # => 'There are no butterflies in the void.'
```