# RegEx for replacing all groups with one row

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group, regex-greedy

For example, I have this string:

```
<ul><li><ahref="http://test.com">sometext</a></li></ul>
```

and I want this output:

```
<ul><li>[URL href="http://test.com"]sometext[/URL]</li></ul>
```

So I create this regex, to matches `<ahref` - first group, `">` - second group and `</a>` - third group, to replace them with `[URL` for first group, `"]` for second group and `[/URL]` for third group:

```
pattern = r'(<a ?href).+(">).+(<\/a>)'
```

It matches the groups, but now I don't know how to replace them.

Comment: is it not just a string, but html file?

Comment: have you tried [```re.sub```](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142327/how-to-replace-multiple-matches-groups-with-python-regexes)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Look for solution only for this case : ))

Comment: @Xosrov I tried with `re.sub` but it replace me whole match, not just the groups

Comment: You can use `re.sub` if you group the things you _not_ want to change and refer to them in replacement as `\1`, `\2`

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm, if it's for html file - I would recommend a more robust approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we would capture what we wish to replace using 4 capturing groups, with an expression similar to:

```
(<ul><li>)<a\s+href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)<\/a>(<\/li><\/ul>)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/kA13u3/1/)

For missing space, we would simply use:

```
(<ul><li>)<ahref=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)<\/a>(<\/li><\/ul>)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/g0hQcD/1/)

If we might have both instances, we would add an optional space group using a capturing or non-capturing group:

```
(<ul><li>)<a(\s+)?href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)<\/a>(<\/li><\/ul>)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/wu9vyf/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<ul><li>)<a\s+href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)<\/a>(<\/li><\/ul>)"

test_str = "<ul><li><a href=\"http://test.com\">sometext</a></li></ul>
"

subst = "\\1[URL href=\"\\2\"]\\3[/URL]\\4"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: So .. you replace everything except groups ?

Comment: Thank you! But i'm curious, is there a way to said something like "replace group 1 from this match of this string with something"

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = "<ul><li><ahref=\"http://test.com\">sometext</a></li></ul>"
pattern = r'(<a ?href).+(">).+(<\/a>)'
url = re.findall('".*"', text)[0]
value = re.findall('>\w+<', text)[0][1:-1]
new_text = re.sub(pattern, '[URL href=' + url + "]" + value + '[/URL]', text)
print(new_text)
```